# Word/phrase meaning an action is appropriate and should be encouraged

Tags: single-word-requests

The context is:

> The police, [appropriately so], are subject to a high level of scrutiny.

Are there any other terms I can use here?

Comment: The use of commas with brackets is clumsy at best. The police are subject to a high level of scrutiny (and appropriately so).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - The use of _square_ brackets here is to show that this is the term that I'm wanting to replace.

Comment: It's non-conventional (check [here](http://www.videojug.com/film/how-to-use-parentheses-and-square-brackets) and certainly misled me. Italics and a reference ('Are there any other terms I can use in place of the italicised string?') would clarify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*The police are **rightly** subject to **a** high level of scrutiny* (also note missing article has been added)

> [**rightly**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rightly) *- in accordance with justice or what is morally right*

Comment: Thaks, that's a typo. It's amusing that two of the answers have reproduced it.

Answer (score 2):

The police, **fittingly** so, are subject to high level of scrutiny.

My edit:
**Fittingly**, The police are subject to high level of scrutiny.

Answer (score 1):

*The police are subject to a high level of scrutiny -- [**and rightfully so**](http://seattlest.com/2011/07/14/seattlest_standoff_two_opinions_on.php)*.

> **[rightful](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rightful)**: according to the law; proper or appropriate.

Comment: The wording would be less awkward if the sentence was not unnecessarily interrupted by the parenthetical clause. Placing it at the end would greatly improve both the flow and the rhetorical impact: "The police are subject to a high level of scrutiny -- [and] rightfully so".

Answer (score 0):

**"as it ought to be"** would fit. It is a common adverbial phrase. ("it" can be replaced with "he", "she", "they" depending on the context)

> **[ought to](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ought-to)** 
>   **1** used to say what is the right thing to do 
>   **2** used to say what you expect or would like to happen

*The police are, as they ought to be, subject to high level of scrutiny.*

Comment: _No_. This is definitely non-standard. I'll reluctantly concede "The police are subject to a high level of scrutiny (as they ought to be)".

Comment: Yes, but you first said "The police, as IT ought to be... " (rather than THEY).

Comment: I thought "it" can refer to the whole idea. I modified my answer. Do you think it is better now?

Comment: Yes, it's a definite improvement. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The police are **deservedly** subject to a high level of scrutiny. **Justly** would also fit.